# Installation of .Net 3.5 runtime is stuck at 17%

Tags: .net, google-compute-engine, windows-server-2016, .net-3.5

I am trying to a .NET framework 3.5 feature on a windows server 2016.

[image]

However once the progress bar reached 17%, it is stuck.

Any reason why it is the case? Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without doing anything, it reaches the end after about 30 minutes. It seems to be a problem with the progress bar in the front end.

Answer (score 3):

Check the error logs and see if you find anything there. Otherwise try to install Net3.5 via CLI.
To do that you would need the Server2016 Image mounted. In my example the image as mounted as Drive D: (change it accordingly)

Restart your server, open up a command prompt as Administrator, type in

Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:Netfx3 /source:D:\Sources\sxs

And wait until its done.